# Clearing textinput in QML

Tags: qt, qml

I have textInput box:

```
TextInput {           
    x: 5
    y: 2
    maximumLength: 16
    width: maximumLength * 20
    height: 17
    focus: false
    validator: RegExpValidator { regExp: /\d+/ }
    KeyNavigation.down: amount
}
```

And a clear button. 
When I click on clear button it should clear the text input box. How to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to add the `id` property to your `TextInput` element.

```
TextInput {
    id: mytextbox
    x: 5
    y: 2
    ...
}
```

And on the event click of your `MouseArea` for your clear button you can do:

```
    onClicked: {
        mytextbox.text = "0"; 
    }
```

Comment: @Kirween why not  `mytextbox.text = "";` to clear text?

Comment: @KernelPanic To match the validator `/regExp: /\d+/` . At least one digit

Answer (score 1):

Try this one with your MouseArea:

```
onClicked: {
  textEdit1.text = " "
  mouseArea4.visible = false
}
```